# Merge [kayak] and [kayaking]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-merge-request

There doesn't seem to be much point in having both a [kayak](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kayak) and [kayaking](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kayaking) tag. They should be merged into one. Most other tags seem to be the activity name, so [kayaking](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kayaking) seems like the choice for which tag to keep in my opinion.

Comment: I see we also have [tag:kayak-plastic] and [tag:kayak-fibreglass] so might just do a merge> all of them into [tag:kayaking]

Comment: @RoryAlsop merging the fibreglass and plastic up could cause people annoyance as they can be handled, and repaired, differently? Kayak + Kayaking should definitely be merged

Comment: I would merge all of them. I already tried to do so but I am not allowed because I've never answered on that badge (which is another story...).

Comment: @RoryAlsop this never got implemented. Could you complete the merge?

Comment: done - had some strange errors come up, but that seems to have worked.